# TLS Extension signature_algorithms values

Tags: tls

I hate asking for a reference, but I'm having a hard time finding this.

The [iana page](https://www.iana.org/assignments/tls-extensiontype-values/tls-extensiontype-values.xhtml) on tls extensions just links me back to [rfc5246](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246) where it only has the following values:

```
enum {
    none(0), md5(1), sha1(2), sha224(3), sha256(4), sha384(5),
    sha512(6), (255)
} HashAlgorithm;

enum { anonymous(0), rsa(1), dsa(2), ecdsa(3), (255) }
  SignatureAlgorithm;
```

I've got a client hello that I'm looking at here with the following signature and hash extension:

> 000d 0014 0012 0403 0804 0401 0503 0805 0501 0806 0601 0201

Where can I find a reference for what these refer to?

Comment: Can you _please_ ASN.1 decode the values you posted?

Comment: @SEJPM It's not ASN.1!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of these values are sort-of defined in drafts that should become RFC at some point. For instance, the latest (as of today) draft of TLS 1.3 lists in [section 4.2.3](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-tls-tls13-28#section-4.2.3) the values 0x0804, 0x0805 and 0x0806 (these designate RSA signatures with the new-style "PSS" padding, used with SHA-256, SHA-384 and SHA-512, respectively).

The "000d 0014 0012" values are actually the header of the extension:

- `000d` is the identifier for the "signature algorithm" extension.
- `0014` is the extension contents length (in bytes).
- `0012` is the length of the list of values in the extension (because the extension is defined as a list of values, and lists in TLS message encodings take an explicit header that gives the list length in bytes).

Note that while the 16-bit values were initially designed as two successive bytes (first for the hash algorithm, second for the signature algorithm), they now tend to be defined as full 16-bit values that cover the whole signature algorithm with no specific sub-structure.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for your help.